# in a makefile, declaring a phony target as a wildcard

Tags: linux, makefile, wildcard

I want to declare my wildcard target as phony, but phony doesn't support wildcards:

My makefile:

```
%.config:
        gcc <<compile>>
```

I want the user to be able to use my makefile to compile the project, using a specific configuration file:

```
make something.config
make something_else.config
```

obviously, I need my target to be phony, becuase the target files exist, but simply writing:

```
.PHONY: %.config
```

doesn't work.
I've seen [here](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_tutorial.html) that makeapp supports another syntax, that would help:

```
$(phony %.config): ...
```

but I can only use make, and not makeapp.

Is there any way to do it with make?

Comment: "I want the user to be able to use my makefile to compile any .c file" What? That's not what make is for.

Comment: It's just an example, to show my problem. In reality, the user runs "make <config file>| and the makefile compiles the code with this coniguration

Comment: @user1340472: Then can you update your question to show code that more accurately reflects what you are trying to do?  `make config_file` doesn't sound a lot like `make source_file.c`...

Answer (score 2):

These are conflicting aims.  A phony target is one that doesn't correspond to a real file.  In your case, the file exists, but it's not really a target.

I would suggest not using the name of the config file as the target.  Instead, construct a system based on one of the following:

```
make something_else
make CONFIG=something_else.config
```