# Why .PHONY:target and not target:.PHONY?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target

I still don't understand why "phony" rules in Makefiles have ".PHONY" as their *target*. It would be much more logical as a *prerequisite*.

Do I have to elaborate on this? If `A` depends on `B` and `B` is phony, then `A` is phony too. So the dependency graph `.PHONY`←`B`→`A` is waay surprising compared to `.PHONY`→`B`→`A`. (Another argument is that an implementation of `make` must handle the `.PHONY` target very special.)

While this critique may seem rather theoretical (to pointless) - "since make is so ancient, its syntax is here to stay". But I am not proposing any syntax change, there is an alternative:

With GNU Make (at least), the following Makefile declares a phony `target_A`:

```
target_A: _PHONY
        touch target_A

_PHONY:
        #noop
```

**Question 1**: *This is so simple and clean, surely I am not its first inventor. In fact, given this alternative, why did `make` ever need the special syntax?*

It seems to me that this would also quite nicely solve questions about [wildcards in phony targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118197/), and could even [shed some light on .PHONY's meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/) when beginners doubt.

**Question 2**: *Can you think of any circumstance where this approach is inferior? (Is invoking `make .PHONY` of any use?)*

(I should mention that while I have invoked other `make`s, GNU Make is the only implementation that I have some experience with - reading and writing Makefiles.)

Comment: (should've RTFM) The GNU Make manual actually [mentions this recipe](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html#Force-Targets) as less efficient, but more portable. I'd conjecture that the speed gains are neglegible. This suggests a negative answer to question 2. (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One big problem with using `target_A: .PHONY` is that it makes it much harder to use many of make's built-in variables.  Take this common recipe as an example:

```
%.a: $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(LD) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

The `$^` variable pulls in *everything* that's listed as a prerequisite.  If `.PHONY` was also listed there then it would be passed to the linker on the command-line, which would probably not result in anything good happening.  Using meta-targets like `.PHONY` as prerequisites makes these built-in variables significantly less useful, as they require a lot of extra processing like `$(filter-out .PHONY,$^)` every time they are used.  Inverting the relationship and instead making `.PHONY` the target is a bit awkward for the sake of thinking about dependency trees, but it cleans up the rest of the makefile.

Comment: Oh, I see. And the presence of [other "special" targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#Special-Targets) - including some that do not fit well (semantically) into the dependency graph at all - seems to mitigate the "why is that so special" objection.